# Google load balancer problem with ssl certificate if url mapping set to custom

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

My load balancer is responsible for two backend services. When the load balancer has the default URL mapping, the SSL certificate works fine. Unfortunately, I want to route all paths with `/api/*` to different backend service and doing so messes with https for my website.
[image]

[image]

After this change, the HTTPS on the address bar is slashed and my website is not secure.

Comment: I have some questions about your issue:

1.-Do you have some re-direct on your VM?
2.- Are you manage the re-direct on your backend? If so, it's probably that the backend "api" is not making this same re-direct.
3.- Could it be that the path /api/ is being calling other elements (from different servers) that is being loading at unsafe way.
4.- Are you performing the request directly on the webrowser using https?

This could help me to understand more your issue, and also, feel free to add as much details as possible

Comment: Actually the frontend and dummy-api-service you see are cloud run endpoints. One is a nginx container and the other is a spring java container to handle rest apis. Backend is simply returning a response in this case I think to the load balancer.

Comment: Which is the error that you are facing when configure the path? Could you please share a screenshot or text about it?